# NodeJS inspector - evaluate with throwOnSideEffect and replMode returns nothing

Tags: node.js, inspector

Node: v16.13.1 under OS: macos 12.2 (Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0)

Under the following circumstance, the evaluate method when used with `replMode` and `throwOnSideEffect` parameters does not do anything. The same method works perfectly when `throwOnSideEffect` and `replMode` are set separately, or when a different expression is provided (such as `1+1`). Evaluating a non existing variable seems not being appealing to NodeJS. I am expecting an `ReferenceError` result but instead the process just returns 0.

I am using the function wrong or I missed something... ?

```js
const inspector = require('inspector');

const session = new inspector.Session();
session.connect();

function myEval(expression, throwOnSideEffect, timeout, replMode) {
    session.post(
        'Runtime.evaluate',
        { expression, throwOnSideEffect, timeout, replMode },
        (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('err');
            }
            return console.log('works', res);
        });
}

// does not work as expected when executed alone
myEval('doesNotExist', true, 200, true);

// works as expected
// myEval(exp, true, 200, false);

// works as expected
// myEval(exp, false, 200, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading node to the version `v17.7.2` resolved the problem.